# RValue references, pointers, and copy constructors

Tags: c++, templates, memory, pointers, rvalue-reference

Consider the following piece of code:

```
int three() {
    return 3;
}

template <typename T>
class Foo {
private:
    T* ptr;

public:
    void bar(T& t) { ptr = new T(t); }
    void bar(const T& t) { ptr = new T(t); }
    void bar(T&& t) { (*ptr) = t; } // <--- Unsafe!
};

int main() {
    Foo<int> foo;

    int a = 3;
    const int b = 3;

    foo.bar(a); // <--- Calls Foo::bar(T& t)
    foo.bar(b); // <--- Calls Foo::bar(const T& t)
    foo.bar(three()); // <--- Calls Foo::bar(T&& t); Runs fine, but only if either of the other two are called first!

    return 0;
}
```

My question is, why does the third overload `Foo::bar(T&& t)` crash the program? What exactly is happening here? Does the parameter `t` get destroyed after the function returns?

Furthermore, let's assume that the template parameter `T` was a very large object with a very costly copy constructor. Is there any way to use RValue References to assign it to `Foo::ptr` without directly accessing this pointer and making a copy?

Comment: Your code as written doesn't cause any problems (apart from a memory leak, and not actually compiling). Is that the actual code that you're using?

Comment: It compiles fine **and** runs fine : http://ideone.com/Ypqxz

Comment: This exact code appears to work fine in Visual Studio 2010 (albeit with memory leaks).  Are you sure your compiler version is compliant in regards to rvalue references?

Comment: @Nawaz: You're not using the OP's code.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I just copy pasted. It's exactly same.

Comment: I apologize. I wrote this code in the question, I didn't compile this as it's not actually my code. mkaes explained why this code compiles and runs fine. But it's unsafe, because if `foo.bar(three())` is called before the other two, it will crash. I tested this.

Comment: @Nawaz: Then you must have had a magic semicolon-insertion clipboard! :-) Now RMF has modified the OP's code, so the comment no longer applies (unless you're a neutrino). RMF: can we roll back the edit so as not to obscure the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this line
`void bar(T&& t) { (*ptr) = t; } // <--- Unsafe!`
you can dereference an uninitialized pointer. This is undefined behavior. 
You must call one of the two other version of bar first because you need to create the memory for your object.
So I would do `ptr = new T(std::move(t));`.
If your type T supports moving the move constructor will get called.

**Update**

I would suggest something like that. Not sure if you need the pointer type within foo:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo {
private:
    T obj;

public:
    void bar(T& t) { obj = t; } // assignment
    void bar(const T& t) { obj = t; } // assignment
    void bar(T&& t) { obj = std::move(t); } // move assign
};
```

This would avoid memory leaks which are also quite easy with your approach.
If you really need the pointer in your class foo how about that:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo {
private:
    T* ptr;

public:
    Foo():ptr(nullptr){}
    ~Foo(){delete ptr;}
    void bar(T& t) { 
        if(ptr)
            (*ptr) = t;
        else
            ptr = new T(t);
    }
    void bar(const T& t) { 
        if(ptr)
            (*ptr) = t;
        else
            ptr = new T(t);
    }
    void bar(T&& t) { 
        if(ptr)
            (*ptr) = std::move(t);
        else
            ptr = new T(std::move(t));
    } 
};
```

Comment: Right, and the other versions of bar are being called first.

Comment: So I should simply create a constructor in `Foo` that would initialize the pointer with `new T()`, and then use the move constructors for `Foo::bar()`? Would that be safe?

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming that you *only* called `foo.bar(three());` without the other two calls:**

Why did you think that'd work? Your code is essentially equivalent to this:

```
int * p;
*p = 3;
```

That's undefined behaviour, because `p` isn't pointing to a valid variable of type `int`.

Comment: p actually points to what has been created by foobar(b), so it's not uninitialized

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia: That's why I added the very extra bold line at the top.

Comment: @Kerreck SB: duh!! I didn't seen that! (My eyes considered it as part of the previous title!  Never start a text with a bold line: looks like belonging to something else)

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason for that to fail in that code. `ptr` will point to an existing `int` object created by the previous calls to `bar` and the third overload will just assign the new value to that object.

However, if you did this instead:

```
int main() {
    Foo<int> foo;

    int a = 3;
    const int b = 3;
    foo.bar(three()); // <--- UB

    return 0;
}
```

That `foo.bar(three());` line would have undefined behaviour (which does not imply any exception), because `ptr` would not be a valid pointer to an `int` object.

Comment: Since I wrote this code on the fly, I realize what you mean. And you're right. It runs fine; but only as long as `foo.bar(three())` is called after either of the other overloads.

Answer (score 0):

The "unsafe"thing, here is that, before assigning to ptr a new object, you should worry about the destiny of what ptr actually points to.

```
foo.bar(three());
```

is unsafe in the sense that you have to grant -before calling it- that ptr actually point to something. In your case it points to what was created by `foo.bar(b);`

But `foobar(b)` makes `ptr` to point to a new object forgetting the one created by `foobar(a)`

A more proper code can be

```
template<class T>
class Foo
{
    T* p;
public:
    Foo() :p() {}
    ~Foo() { delete p; }

    void bar(T& t) { delete p; ptr = new T(t); }
    void bar(const T& t) { delete p; ptr = new T(t); }
    void bar(T&& t) 
    { 
        if(!ptr) ptr = new T(std::move(t));
        else (*ptr) = std::move(t); 
    } 
}
```

;